# How to relocate a library using Python in 2.80 beta?

Tags: python

I would like to, using only Python, relocate a linked library to another file. This is the equivalent of showing the "Blender file" content in the Outliner, right-clicking on the linked library and choosing "Relocate":

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Going step by step in the native Blender code using a debugger, I was able to figure out the properties to give to the operator (which is **wm.lib_relocate**):

```
bpy.ops.wm.lib_relocate(
    library="cube-v02.blend",
    directory="C:\\Users\\someone\\Desktop\\",
    filename="cube-v01.blend"
)
```

Where:

- **library** is the name of the library to relocate which seems to be the file name (without the directory part).
- **directory** is the directory where the new library (blend file) is located.
- **filename** is the file name of the blend file.

Answer (score 1):

A way without an operator

```
lib = bpy.data.libraries["library_name"]
lib.filepath = "new\\path"
lib.reload() # might not be necessary
```